# Why sub-replication is not studied in literature

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics

There are numerous paper about super-hedging and super-replication in an incomplete market where the risk neutral measures are not unique. The most fundamental result is that the super-replication cost equals the maximum of risk neutral expectation of the option. I wonder why no one is studying the dual, sub-replication, and see if it equals the minimum of the risk neutral expectation? Thus we will have an interval for the option price.

Comment: You are right - This is a standard topic in financial economics though

Answer (score 1):

If you denote by $p\left(G\right)$ the super replication of a claim $G$, the sub replication price is simply $-p\left(-G\right)$.

I think I saw that it is the infimum across risk-neutral measures of the (discounted) risk-neutral expectations of $G$ in Bouchard & Chassagneux *Fundamentals and Advanced Techniques in Derivatives Hedging*. Quite mathematical book.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Before I check the paper you mentioned, I think the fact that super-replication equals to the supremum of risk neutral expectation relies on the assumption that the contingent claim is non-negative, which does not apply to $-G$. The proof of the theorem is due to optional decomposition of a non-negative local supermartingale. However, if you truncate the claim, you can indeed apply the theorem to $-(G\wedge n)$. But now the problem is whether this holds true when $n$ goes to infinity. You can see another problem I posted in this regard. Any idea is appreciated!

Comment: Also, in literature, one usually need the assumption that your hedging strategy is admissible, i.e. wealth being bounded from below but possibly unbounded from above. And one can not simply take the opposite position of super-hedging due to such asymmetry.

Comment: I have the version where the claim $G$ is only $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable. However, the portfolio strategy has to be admissible in the sense that the terminal value of your Hedging portfolio $\pm$ the claim $G$ has to be nonnegative. The super-replication price is the smallest price enabling that.

Comment: That makes the unbounded part not contradictory :) basically, the sub-Hedging price is the lowest price a seller can be willing to sell you the claim at: some authors call it the “buyer’s super-replication price”. If you are a buyer, you can totally agree to sell $-G$, i.e. will have to receive $G$ at maturity, and the whole idea of the Hedging part would be to capture the premium.

Comment: Wow, could you share the reference where $G$ is only $\mathcal F_T$ measurable? I think in Bouchard it is still assumed that $G$ is bounded from below, i.e. $G^- \in L^{\infty}$

Comment: And I think for the super-replication case, the strategy is admissible as long as the wealth - $G$ is non-negative? I dont think it need be $\pm G$.

Comment: The $\pm$ thing is merely to distinguish the buying or selling the claim. For the measurable thing, this is in Bouchard's initial assumptions set (p.13, section **1.3 European option pricing**)

Comment: And in Bouchard, it is not explicitly assumed that the claim is **simply** bounded, though the author indeed puts some (quite vague) constraints on $G^-$. But that does not mean that $p\left(-G\right)$ the super-replication price of $-G$ is undefined !